# MVP or MVVM for Android with respect to Unit Testing?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mvvm, mvp

Have used MVP model in one module of my android app with the help of which code was testable and I was able to run Unit test via that code.
Now I researched for MVVM model, my main focus is to make my code testable, can MVVM model could help me better than MVP model??

Comment: which architecture did you prefer for implementation? I too have the same query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit testing for the MVP or MVVM are easy to implement with the help of Mockito.
But the only difference is MVVM architecture is bit more complex then MVP.If you are comfortable with subscribers,dependencies injections etc then go for MVVM otherwise till now MVP is the best.

You can check this [link](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-2f12e1c7d4db) or [this](https://medium.com/upday-devs/android-architecture-patterns-part-3-model-view-viewmodel-e7eeee76b73b) for more details.